# Related to multiplicative subgroup of positive real line

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $F$ be a subgroup of the multiplicative group $\mathbb R^*_{>0}$ such that  $F$ is dense in $\mathbb R^*_{>0}$, 
>   $$N\cap F=\emptyset\ \text{ and }\ NF=N,$$
>   in which  $N$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^*_{>0}$. Can one conclude that $N=\emptyset$?

You can also add the following assumptions: 
$$x\in F \ \ \rightarrow \ \ \  \sqrt x \in F;$$
$$x\in N \ \ \rightarrow \ \ \  \sqrt x \in N;$$
$$x\in N,\ n\in \mathbb{N}\ \ \rightarrow \ \ \   x^n \in N.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $N$ be the set of positive real numbers which are transcedental over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Let $F$ be the set of positive real numbers which are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.